# Examples of Cohen-Macaulay integral domains

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, integral-domain, cohen-macaulay

**Question 1** Could you find a non Cohen-Macaulay ring $A$ without zero divisors.

I would like $A$ to be as simple as possible. For instance, I want $A$ to be finitely generated alegbra over $\mathbb{C}$.

**Comment** I found plenty of examples of non Cohen-Macaulay rings in wiki and from other sources. But those rings are not integral domains.

**Question 2** A projective curve is called ACM if it's homogeneous coordinate ring is Cohen-Macaulay. It would be great if one give me an example of non ACM curve in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Since any one-dimensional integral domain is CM, let's look a little further. Then we find the two-dimensional ring $R=K[X^4,X^3Y,XY^3,Y^4]$ which [is not CM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517961/why-is-this-ring-not-cohen-macaulay).
2. $R=K[X,Y,Z,W]/(X,W)\cap(Y,Z)$ (the disjoint union of two lines in $\mathbb P^3$) [is not CM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1413766/prove-that-kx-1-ldots-x-4-langle-x-1x-2-x-2x-3-x-3x-4-x-4x-1-rangle-is).

(The example given in 1. is also good as it is the coordinate ring of the rational quartic curve in $\mathbb P^3$, that is, $K[a,b,c,d]/(ad-bc, a^2c-b^3, bd^2-c^3, ac^2-b^2d)$.)