# Subring of a Cohen-Macaulay ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

I try to find a obvious of this example: Subring of a Cohen-Macaulay ring is not Cohen-Macaulay. However, I got stuck.

Could you help me say it in more detail? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3):

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517961/why-is-this-ring-not-cohen-macaulay) contains the example $$K[x^4, x^3 y, xy^3, y^4] \subseteq K[x,y]$$ where $K$ is a field. Also any integral domain that is not CM can be viewed as a subring of its field of fractions.